# json: error calling MarshalJSON for type main.Time: invalid character '-' after top-level value

Tags: json, go

I intent to serialize `time.Time` to have UTC timezone and in RFC3339 format.
So I created following custom data type called `Time` that embeds `time.Time`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "time"
)

type Time struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t *Time) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    ret, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, string(b))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *t = Time{ret}
    return nil
}

func (t Time) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(t.UTC().Format(time.RFC3339)), nil
}

func main() {
    type User struct {
        CreatedAt Time `json:"created_at"`
    }

    user := User{CreatedAt: Time{time.Now()}}
    _, err := json.Marshal(user)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

When this data is tried to marshal with `json.Marshal` I get following error

```
json: error calling MarshalJSON for type main.Time: invalid character '-' after top-level value
```

I have 2 queries

1. Why above code is throwing the error?
2. Is this the right way to serialise and deserialise `time.Time` to and from a desired format in an API

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The output of your custom MarshalJSON is an unquoted string with `-` separating different integers or whatever that denote the different parts of the timstamp. That's not valid JSON. You may do this: https://go.dev/play/p/1JKdYv9J3su, but be careful with this naive approach, while in your specific case it's fine in other cases a custom string may need proper JSON *escaping* and should therefore be run through json.Marshal like this: https://go.dev/play/p/nKpH3IbJoqc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text `2009-11-10T23:00:00Z` is not a valid JSON value, but `"2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"` is. Note the quotes.

Use the following function to format Time as a JSON string.

```
func (t Time) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    b := make([]byte, 0, len(time.RFC3339)+2)
    b = append(b, '"')
    b = t.AppendFormat(b, time.RFC3339)
    b = append(b, '"')
    return b, nil
}
```